# ifup/ifdown scripts

Tags: wi-fi, networking, scripts, init.d

I am fiddeling with some network related things and want to try them on Android too. In Ubuntu it was quite easy to run some commands if an interface (eth0 or wlan0) goes up or down by simply adding the script call to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

How can I do that in Android?

There is no such file, and I could not find a way to have my script executed on every network up/down.

I have root, and I am running the latest CyanogenMod. I would also switch the ROM if needed.